# Restore deleted images (png/gif/jpg/jpeg)

Tags: data-recovery, images, deleted-files

I inadvertently deleted images from my Linux filesystem today with classic command `rm -f`.

All deleted images were in one single folder. Not all my images were in this folder, it was only very specific images.

Is there a way to restore them by a command? I read about some revocery like `debugfs`, `PhotoRec`, ...

Comment: The simplest command to restore them would be the one that uses your backup copy. You haven't said, so it's reasonable to assume you do **not** have a backup, but you could clarify that in your post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to be more specific about the system environment, but assuming your file system is formatted as ext3 or ext4 (which should be the default in modern Linux systems - check the output of `mount`), you can try a tool called `extundelete`.

**Note, however,** that any action that possibly alters the file system on which these files were located must be avoided, so if at all possible unmount it before installing anything on your computer. Ideally, perform the recovery on *a different computer* where you attach the hard drive in question as external drive with a suitable adaptor. Also, given the design of the ext file system, no success is guaranteed.

And, I would advise that you make a **habit of backing up your files regularly** (as boring as that may sound).